# Looking to simplify chain of if statements in C

Tags: c, if-statement, counter

I need to simplify 4 if statements into something only a few lines for a project.

I can't seem to figure out how to do that.

```
         if(apple == 1){
             one++;
         }
         if(apple == 2){
             two++;
         }
         if(apple == 3){
             three++;
         }
         if(apple == 4){
             four++;
         }
```

Comment: You can use an array:  total[apple]++

Comment: I'm not really sure how much more you can cut from that.  It's pretty much as concise as it can be.  Maybe use the ? ternary operator you could get it down to a line but in my opinion that would be pretty hard reading.  Or a Switch statement, but that isn't going to cut it down any

Comment: At the very least add `else` statements. if apple==1 it's not going to ==2 etc.

Answer (score 3):

Use a switch statement instead:

```
   switch(apple){
        case 1: 
            one++;
            break;
        case 2:
            two++;
            break;
        case 3:
            three++;
            break;
        case 4:
            four++;
            break;
        default:
            printf("No value!\n");
    }
```

Alternatively, you may do something like this to get rid of those four variables (labeled: `one`, `two`, `three`, `four`):

```
position[apple]++;
printf("Data[%d]: %d", apple, position[apple]);
```

This is one array without switch or if statements, just one variable where the position is decided with your `apple` variable as index.

Comment: position[apple]=++position[apple]; is redundant.  The increment will update position[apple] so you don't need to assign it.

Comment: @jmq I knew someone was going to ask, but I still didn't make a comment on it. Changing it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how specific you need this to be. What is the goal your program is attempting to accomplish?

You could use an array to represent the variables `one`, `two`, etc. For example:

```
foo[apple]++;
```

using `apple` as your index removes the need for `if` statements entirely.

If you really need to use `if` statements you should `else if`. Generally it's a good idea to place mutually exclusive statements into `else if` blocks so the code doesn't check every possibility every time.

```
if (apple == 1) {
  one++;
} 
else if (apple == 2) {
  two++;
}
//This way if apple == 1, we don't ever run the other if statement!
```